# how to create all dynamic ubercart product images for CDN module to sync

Tags: ubercart, cdn

I have enable CDN module to handle image/css and js requests from a static server.
As drupal creates product images for different styles dynamically there are many products whose images are not present at the time to CDN and my domains syncing of images.
How can i handle the request to new product images in this scenario >
Right now the missing images are coming blank

Answer (score 0):

This worked with the following setting in default/settings.php file

$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;